# Finding coherence of two signals

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to find coherence between two signals. I used `mscohere` function but the result looks noise because the signal is long `(100000)`. So, I divided the signal into a record and try to find coherence from `(coherence=abs(Pxy)/sqrt(Pxx*Pyy))`. I found the `Pxx` and `Pyy` and both of them have `1000` records. However, when I tried to find `Pxy` the number of points that I got it is `(129)` points. and the program not working. I do not know the reason for that

```
N=100000;
SF=1000;       
A=sin(2*pi*100*t)+0.5*sin(2*pi*300*t);
Y=0.8*randn(1,length(A))+A;
D=reshape(A(1,1:100000),[1000,100]).';
M=length(D(1,:));
D1=reshape(Y(1,1:100000),[1000,100]).';
M1=length(D1(1,:));
for i=1:100
    FFT_A(i,:)=fft(D(i,:));
    S_A(i,:)=(FFT_A(i,:).*conj(FFT_A(i,:)))/M;
    FFT_Y(i,:)=fft(D1(i,:));
    S_Y(i,:)=(FFT_Y(i,:).*conj(FFT2_Y(i,:)))/M;
    Pxy (i,:)= cpsd(D(i,:),D1(i,:));
end
S_A_F=sum(S_A);
S_Y_F=sum(S_Y);
Pxy_F=sum(Pxy);
coherence=abs(Pxy_F)./sqrt(S_A_F.*S_Y_F);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your output domain selection is inconsistent between the autocorrelation and the cross-correlation. Might I suggest using a consistent analysis for both measures.

```
Pxx = cpsd( D, D);%auto-spectra D
Pyy = cpsd( D1, D1);%auto-spectra D1
Pxy = cpsd( D, D1);%cross-spectra D-D1  

coherence = abs(Pxy.*conj(Pxy))./(Pxx.*Pyy);
```

Comment: Thank you. The signal is long and the result will e noisy. I have to divide the signal into records.